# Can anyone check if this is correct?

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

There are 6 woman and 4 men. how many ways can they be arranged so that there is a woman at the start and at the end of the row and no two men are together?

what i did is $6\cdot5\cdot2\cdot4!\cdot4! = 34560$

Comment: Seems right; $6 \cdot 5$ ways to arrange the two women on the end, then the middle has to be either $MWMWMWMW$ or $WMWMWMWM$, each with $4! \cdot 4!$ possible arrangements of the women and men. Thus, $6 \cdot 5 \cdot 2 \cdot 4! \cdot 4!$.

Comment: Isn't it simply $6!\cdot4!$?

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer is $86400$:

Arrange the women: $6!$ ways.  There are now $5$ possible spots for men: W-W-W-W-W-W (we must pick four of the five spots between two women to place the men).  There are $5$ ways to choose $4$ of these $5$ spots.  There are then $4!$ ways to arrange the men.

Total: $6!\cdot 5\cdot 4!=86400$.

This agrees with mvw's answer, but arrived at differently.

Comment: Going for the feasible spots, that is it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To preserve my mental sanity I wrote a Ruby [program](https://gist.github.com/8e935644a8dddcd0da1a) to brute force this.
It reports

```
n = 86400
```

combinations. Of the $10!$ permutations

```
ne = 2419200
```

were invalid due to guys sticking to a table end and

```
n2 = 1123200
```

due to guys sitting next to each other and creating trouble.

This result is half of my original attempt to join $5$ women with $4$ guys ($5! \cdot 4!)$ and then letting the $6$-th woman choose one of ten positions (inflating it by $10$).

Looking at a simpler example ($3$ women and $1$ man), I noted that half the permutations plus choice result in a repetition, like $1m2, 3 \to 31m2$ ($3$ choosing first position) and $3m2, 1 \to 31m2$ ($1$ choosing second position). 
It were just the permutations which had a different sign, which hints to a difference of one transposition. So there might be some algebraic argument possible.

Note: Beware of programming errors :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are $\binom{6}{2}$ to choose two women who have to be kept at the end of the row and $2!$ ways of arranging them. The rest of the 8 places can be filled by women in 8 places as $4!$ and similarly, the men can be arranged in $4!$ ways.

So, the final answer on simplification turns out to be:  $6.5.4!.4! = 17280$ ways.